# Subsetting rows with "_" in one column in R

Tags: r, special-characters, subset

I have a data frame that contains of over 10000 rows and approximately 20 columns. 
The ID column includes some entries that have a "_ "  separating two or more numbers/words etc.
How do I subset only rows that have a "_ " in the ID column into a separate data frame?

Comment: Try `df[grepl("_",df$ID),]`.

Answer (score 2):

The `str_detect` function from `stringr` is helpful here. Now that the package is included with version 1.2 of the `tidyverse` package, the following code should work:

```
library(tidyverse)

filtered_df <- df %>%
  filter(str_detect(ID, "_"))
```

This line of code will return `filtered_df`, a data frame based on `df` that only includes the rows where the `ID` column includes an underscore.